# Can I charge my van's car battery directly from its lithium ion "house battery"?

Tags: lithium-ion, automotive

I have a 1991 GMC van that I've converted into a poor man's RV.  I've got a [Yeti 1000](https://www.goalzero.com/shop/archive-power/goal-zero-yeti-1000-lithium-portable-power-station/) lithium ion house battery, and a 100 watt Renogy solar panel on the roof.  When the battery has died in the past, I have hooked the ~20v solar panel output directly to the car battery and successfully charged it (checking voltage on the car battery regularly to make sure I don't overcharge).  Can I do the same thing using the 12V output from the house battery?  I'm mostly concerned with damage to the house battery, which costs over $1000.

My exact question is this: If my 12v lead acid starter battery goes dead, can I connect the 12v output (I measure 12.4v) of the Yeti 1000 directly to my starter battery to charge it enough to start the car, as long as I am careful to monitor it to prevent overcharging? And is there any way this might damage my yeti 1000?

Comment: A "12V" vehicle battery needs a battery charger with about 13.5V to 14.4V and its current limited. Your house battery cannot do it. Connect a proper 120VAC powered vehicle battery charger to the house battery 120VAC output.

Comment: Not directly but you can buy a DC-DC charger that will do the job. Only you can decide if it is worth it.

Comment: So, what you are asking is, if your 12V lead acid starter battery goes dead, can you recharge it by direct-connecting the yeti 100 battery to the lead acid battery? Is that your question? Or are you asking if you can direct connect the solar panel to the house battery? Very unclear!

Comment: Sorry keith, but yes, that is the right question. I will update the question woth your precise terminology.

Comment: I added a more exact restatement of the question after the context.

Comment: You definitely cannot just connect the batteries together directly. That could damage either or both batteries and maybe give you a big spark, too. Victron makes a battery-to-battery charger that you could use for that purpose. Victron Orion TR. https://www.amazon.com/Victron-Energy-Orion-Tr-Isolated-Converter/dp/B01M0YCDJ8. And when I say big spark, I mean the kind that can blast little bits of molten copper in all directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New question.

Maybe, the 10A 12V limit will be exceeded with a dead battery so a 10A 12V lamps in series might be possible to use as a current limiter to get 50% charge @ 12V.

---

“ The Goal Zero Yeti 1000 Lithium can be charged in 9 - 18 hours by plugging into your vehicle's 12V outlet using the Goal Zero Yeti Lithium 12V Car Charging Cable. NOTE: Do not attempt to charge your Yeti Lithium from a 12V source using any other cable. Doing so may cause damage to the unit”

- it must be able to measure battery current independent of the load to limit the exposure time during CV soak overcharge.
- keep a record of voltage in each cell monthly.  When one drops, it is a sign of end of life.  The battery is only as good as the weakest cell. Each cell must very well matched. If the entire string is ok but 1 cell is overcharged or under, this stage of aging will deteriorate rapidly under the balancer does its job.

Comment: Thanks Tony, but I think my question was poorly phrased and you answered a different question. I have updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Maybe, the 10A 12V limit will be exceeded with a dead battery so a 10A 12V lamps in series might be possible to use as a current limiter to get 50% charge @ 12V

Comment: You can’t down vote for asking the wrong question